# How to access req/res outside of route handler in express/node

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, routes

Very simply, I'm mapping a route in my express/node app to a method in another module. On completion, an event is dispatched. All works great, but how do I get at res in my 'on_products' event handler?

Here is the general idea:

```
Routes = (app) ->

  eventbus.on 'on_products', -> res.send 'some products' #how do i get at res here?

  app.get '/products', (req,res) ->  getProducts() 

module.exports = Routes
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass along arguments when you trigger the event:

```
eventbus.emit 'on_products', res
```

And use that in the event handler:

```
eventbus.on 'on_products', (res) ->
  res.send 'some products'
```

Comment: Thanks Linus. I had hoped that I could reference res without having to pass it around, because it gets passed round full circle.ie The controller accesses a service. The service ultimately dispatches the event that the controller ends up handling again. It seems like I'm having to weave res all the way around back to it's starting location.

Comment: Brad: Ok. I find it hard to reason about your code without having seen it, but I think that you'll find it hard to keep the response in scope without passing it around.